# How to print using indexes?

Tags: go

Is there a way to print using variable indexes?

```
fmt.Fprintf("%[1] %[2] %[3] %[4]", a, b, c, d)
```

I get errors about

> string does not implement io.Writer

Using `fmt.Println` prints the variable indexes as a literal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> Explicit argument indexes:
>
> In Printf, Sprintf, and Fprintf, the default behavior is for each
>   formatting verb to format successive arguments passed in the call.
>   However, the notation [n] immediately before the verb indicates that
>   the nth one-indexed argument is to be formatted instead. The same
>   notation before a '*' for a width or precision selects the argument
>   index holding the value. After processing a bracketed expression [n],
>   subsequent verbs will use arguments n+1, n+2, etc. unless otherwise
>   directed.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> fmt.Sprintf("%[2]d %[1]d\n", 11, 22)
> ```
>
> will yield "22 11"
>
> [func Fprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf)
>
> ```
> func Fprintf(w io.Writer, format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Fprintf formats according to a format specifier and writes to w. It
>   returns the number of bytes written and any write error encountered.
>
> [func Printf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf)
>
> ```
> func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Printf formats according to a format specifier and writes to standard
>   output. It returns the number of bytes written and any write error
>   encountered.

For `Fprintf` provide an `io.Writer`or use `Printf`. Also, add format 'verbs' to your format specifier. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    a, b, c, d := 1, 2, 3, 4
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%[1]d %[2]d %[3]d %[4]d\n", a, b, c, d)
    fmt.Printf("%[1]d %[2]d %[3]d %[4]d\n", a, b, c, d)
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

fmt.Fprintf has definition:
`func Fprintf(w io.Writer, format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`
So you need to provide writer.

For indexing you can use format like this: `"%[2]d %[1]d"`